# Moving an object based on its rotation

Tags: java, libgdx

I have this ship sprite (prototype for now) and I've been trying to move it along its rotation but it is not working so well. 
<-- Vid --> 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/W64bS.jpg 
<-- Example Image of what I think should happen -->
[image]
When researching, I saw that sometimes the cosine is for the x position and the sign is for the y position, this makes me a little confused about what to do. But sometimes I saw otherwise which makes me wonder since I thought the x should be using sine and y should be cosine.

Code:

```
package com.lance.seajam;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Input.Keys;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Texture;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import java.lang.Math;

public class Player {
    private final float rotSpeed;
    private final float movementSpeed;

    private final Texture texture;
    private final int textureWidth;
    private final int textureHeight;
    private final SpriteBatch batch;
    private Vector2 position;
    private int rotation;
    private float originX;
    private float originY;
    private int realRot;

    private double DEG2RAD = 180 / Math.PI;

    public Player(Texture texture, SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.batch = batch;
        this.rotation = 0;
        this.textureWidth = texture.getWidth();
        this.textureHeight = texture.getHeight();
        this.position = new Vector2(300, 300);

        this.originX = textureWidth/2;
        this.originY = textureHeight/2;
        this.rotSpeed = 3f;
        this.movementSpeed = 3f;
    }

    public void Movement() {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.A)) rotation += rotSpeed;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.D)) rotation -= rotSpeed;

        realRot = rotation;

        if (rotation >= 360) realRot = 360;
        if (rotation <= 0) realRot = 0;

        double xVel = 0;
        double yVel = 0;

        xVel += Math.cos(realRot) * movementSpeed;
        yVel += Math.sin(realRot) * movementSpeed;

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Keys.W)) {
            position.x += xVel;
            position.y += yVel;
        }

        System.out.println(xVel);
    }

    public void DrawSprite() {
        batch.draw (
            texture, position.x, position.y,
            originX, originY, textureWidth,
            textureHeight, 1, 1,
            rotation, 1, 1, textureWidth,
            textureHeight, false, false
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: There's something weird: you *always* modify the velocity, but only actually move the object when the button is pressed? That seems exactly the wrong way around: you want to only change the velocity if the button is pressed but always change the position (assuming you want inertia, which your code and video suggests).

Comment: sin is vertical, cosin is horizontal (as long as you take the angle from the horizontal axis).

Comment: Also: you don't want to "clamp" rotation to 0/360, you want it to "slide over" from being > 360 to being just above 0. I.e. `while (rotation > 360) rotation -= 360`. Otherwise you'll get a weird "stop" when facing north and rotation won't be smooth there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an extra `Vector2` member, `direction` in your `Player` class you can get **libGDX** to calculate the `x` and `y` delta by using the `rotateDeg` method on `Vector2`:

```
direction.set(Vector2.X).rotateDeg(realRot);
```

This will set `direction` to *(1, 0)* and then rotate it by your rotation amount.
Then you can just add `direction.x` and `direction.y` to your `position`.

```
position.x += direction.x;
position.y += direction.y;
```

or even shorter:

```
position.add(direction);
```

[image]

Full source for `Player` for the above animation is:

```
public class Player {
    private final float rotSpeed;
    private final float movementSpeed;

    private final Texture texture;
    private final int textureWidth;
    private final int textureHeight;
    private final SpriteBatch batch;
    private Vector2 position;
    private Vector2 direction = new Vector2(Vector2.X); // Add this
    private int rotation;
    private float originX;
    private float originY;
    private int realRot;

    private double DEG2RAD = 180 / Math.PI;

    public Player(Texture texture, SpriteBatch batch) {
        this.texture = texture;
        this.batch = batch;
        this.rotation = 0;
        this.textureWidth = texture.getWidth();
        this.textureHeight = texture.getHeight();
        this.position = new Vector2(0, 0);

        this.originX = textureWidth/2;
        this.originY = textureHeight/2;
        this.rotSpeed = 3f;
        this.movementSpeed = 3f;
    }

    public void Movement() {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) rotation += rotSpeed;
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.D)) rotation -= rotSpeed;

        realRot = rotation;

        // You don't really need this
        //if (rotation >= 360) realRot = 360;
        //if (rotation <= 0) realRot = 0;

        // At each update, set the direction vector to point to the right, and then rotate
        // it using your readRot variable.
        direction.set(Vector2.X).rotateDeg(realRot);

        direction.scl(movementSpeed); // Scale the direction by you speed

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.W)) {
            position.x += direction.x;
            position.y += direction.y;
        }
    }

    public void DrawSprite() {
        batch.draw (
                texture, position.x, position.y,
                originX, originY, textureWidth,
                textureHeight, 1, 1,
                rotation, 1, 1, textureWidth,
                textureHeight, false, false
        );
    }
}
```